# Unity: How do I use a function from another script using a sting as it's name?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've been banging my head on the wall for the past 32 hours looking for an answer to this one.
So I want to access a public void from another script by using a string so I won't be using 100 if statements.
All answers I've seen online either contradict other answer, they don't explain their very complicated code well enough or they just don't work.

Comment: The other answers are clear: use reflection ... if you do not understand how to use it use "100 ifs"

Comment: **Why** do you want to use its name in the first place? And you might want to use e.g. [`GameObject.SendMessage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictonary containing strings as keys and delegates as values, so you can assign your functions to the delegates and give it a name. In the other script you can acces the dictonary and call the function with the corresponding name. Im not sure if this is what youre looking for, but I hope it helps.